# missing maven 2/3 job type from the list of available type for a new job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

missing maven 2/3 job type from the list of available type for a new job.
I have jenkins version - 1.568
maven version 2.2.1 and Maven integration plugin is in enable state,

Please provide any hint How can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Maven Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin):

Since version 2.0 this plugin is released separately